# Why is accordion() not a function when trying to refresh an existing accordion()?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

**UPDATE** I honestly am not sure how the context was lost, but after forcing explicit context by changing all `jQuery('.sections')` to `var sections = jQuery('.sections')` so that I could change all `jQuery('.parts')` to `jQuery('.parts', sections)`, has allowed me to use accordion() anywhere once again.

Here is the working version of the code below for any future visitors...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var layout_sections = jQuery('.sections');

    /* retrieve the settings fields markup via AJAX. */    
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {}, function(response){
        layout_sections.append(response).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: 'content',
            header: '> .section > .section-title'
        }).sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            handle: '.section-title',
            stop: function(e, ui){
                ui.item.children('.section-title').triggerHandler('focusout');
            }
        });

        jQuery('.parts', layout_sections).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: 'content',
            header: '> .part > .part-title'
        }).sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            handle: '.part-title',
            stop: function(e, ui){
                ui.item.children('.part-title').triggerHandler('focusout');
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.do-new-section', function(e){

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {}, function(response){
            layout_sections.append(response).accordion('refresh');
            jQuery('.parts', layout_sections).accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: 'content',
                header: '> .part > .part-title'
            }).sortable({
                axis: 'y',
                handle: '.part-title',
                stop: function(e, ui){
                    ui.item.children('.part-title').triggerHandler('focusout');
                }
            });
        });

    }).on('click', '.do-new-part', function(e){

      var parts_target = jQuery('#parts-id', layout_sections);

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {}, function(response){
            parts_target.append(response).accordion('refresh');
        });

    });

});
```

---

When adding items to a nested accordion, I'm not able to refresh the stack because `accordion() is not a function` despite it already being called successfully twice already. [You can see the .parts div has been initialized but still fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqw8P.png).

Which by my understanding makes even less sense because [Unlike other widget methods, instance() is safe to call on any element after the accordion plugin has loaded.](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-instance)

This is running inside of a WordPress metabox, and all of the scripts are properly loading with the one true method for loading them...

`wp_enqueue_script('plugin-js', PLUGIN_ASSETS . 'js/metabox.js', ['jquery', 'jquery-ui-accordion', 'jquery-ui-sortable', 'jquery-ui-tabs'], false, false);`

Here are the relevant parts of `metabox.js` with all the return falses and such removed...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    /* retrieve the settings fields markup via AJAX. */    
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {}, function(response){
        jQuery('.sections').append(response).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: 'content',
            header: '> .section > .section-title'
        }).sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            handle: '.section-title',
            stop: function(e, ui){
                ui.item.children('.section-title').triggerHandler('focusout');
            }
        }).find('.parts').accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: 'content',
            header: '> .part > .part-title'
        }).sortable({
            axis: 'y',
            handle: '.part-title',
            stop: function(e, ui){
                ui.item.children('.part-title').triggerHandler('focusout');
            }
        });
    });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.do-new-section', function(e){

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {}, function(response){   jQuery('.sections').append(response).accordion('refresh').find('.parts').accordion({
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: 'content',
                header: '> .part > .part-title'
            }).sortable({
                axis: 'y',
                handle: '.part-title',
                stop: function(e, ui){
                    ui.item.children('.part-title').triggerHandler('focusout');
                }
            });
        });

    }).on('click', '.do-new-part', function(e){

        /* This is there I'm having issues calling accordion(), the function just doesn't exist when referencing the desired element. */
        var parts_target = jQuery(this).parents('.section-fields').find('.parts');

        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {}, function(response){
            parts_target.append(response).accordion('refresh');
        });

    });

});
```

Here's a stripped down snippet of the markup that is returned via AJAX...

```
<div class="sections">
    <div class="section">
        <div class="section-title">
            Banner Slideshow
        </div>
        <div class="section-fields">
            <a class="do-new-part" href="#">
                Add slides
            </a>
            <div class="parts">
                <div class="part">
                    <div class="part-title">
                        Slide
                    </div>
                    <div class="part-fields">
                        Slide fields
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd appreciate any fresh set of eyes on this as I've exhausted my searching (this is a similar error caused by broken dependencies, which isn't the case).

Comment: Try saving the each `accordion` into a variable via `.accordion("instance")` directly after the first calls. Would be informative to check them inside the click handler.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in but I wasn't even able to do that. The top level accordion initializes fine when called from the AJAX response but immediately after I have `layout_sections.find('.parts').each(function(){ var parts = jQuery(this).accordion('instance'); accordions.push(parts); });` and get `accordion is not a function`.

Comment: The accordion API states: `Retrieves the accordion's instance object. If the element does not have an associated instance, undefined is returned.` This should return `undefined` not `accordion is not a function`. Are you sure accordion library is still in context?

Comment: You just helped me solve something which has been traumatizing me for weeks. I modified my code to use context in the selectors and that seemed to fix it. Please continue to travel the internet telling people to check their context. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: Sweet. Dirty ole context.